# converting a csv file to arff file using weka converter

Tags: weka

I am trying to convert a spreadsheet on a csv file to a arff file on Weka 3.8.6, when opening the file in the Explorer section of the program. It is showing this message:
weka.core.converters.csvLoader failed to load 'housing_test.csv'.
reason:
index 22 out of bounds for length 22 Problem encountered on line 91.

I am very new too Weka, so don't know what this message means.
[message displayed when converting the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QarNM.png)

I am trying to convert a CSV to ARFF using Weka's CSVLoader from the GUI. In the options I set the enclosure character for strings to be ", although there are no quotes in my file. I get the following error:

weka.core.converters.CSVLoaderfailed to lead 
Reason:
wrong number of values. Read 20, expected 22, read Token[EOL], line 3215

Here is line 3215
7046602013,https://cleveland.craigslist.org/apa/d/lakewood-west-lakewood-upstairs-2-bdrm/7046602013.html,cleveland,https://cleveland.craigslist.org,1100,apartment,900,2,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,w/d hookups,,yes,"2 bedroom upstairs apartment in West Lakewood with updated kitchen and bathroom including central air and dishwasher. 7 minute walk to both Downtown Lakewood and Lakewood Park. Large balcony. Hookups for washer and dryer in basement. Short term lease with opportunity for extension. First month's rent and deposit due upon signing of lease.",41.4902,-81.8058,oh

Any Ideas? I can't find an error

Comment: Based on your header row, the CSVLoader expected 22 columns but only found 20. The row that you posted contains double quotes around the description of the property. Weka's CSVLoader is quite sensitive and does not handle common CSV formats very well (cells with blanks usually need to be quoted, other quotes or commas usually have to be escaped with \). You could try the [common-csv](https://github.com/fracpete/common-csv-weka-package) Weka package as an alternative.